# triggering events from nested widgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've built a really simple jquery ui widget that just creates a slider and tries to bubble up the slide event. The code is below. However, this._trigger is undefined in this context. How would I re-trigger the event in this case?

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.timelineSlider", {
        options : {
        },

        _create : function() {
            var self = this;
            var element = self.element;
            var options = self.options;

            element.slider({
            slide:function (e, ui) {
                        this._trigger("slideHappened", null, {date: ui.value});
                }
            });
        },

        destroy : function() {
            this.element.next().remove();
        },

        _setOption : function(option, value) {
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't see `_trigger` anywhere .. what is that?

Comment: _trigger is what the widget factory provides as a method to bubble events..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery will set the invocation context (i.e. `this`) on events bound through it to the DOM node that the event occurred on.  In this case it will be the `div.ui-slider` that the slide occurred on.

To reference the widget from the `slide` handler a reference will have to be saved off that the `slide` method can access.  Luckily you already have one with `var self = this;` in `_create`.

Therefore you can simply replace `this` with `self` and you're good.

**Live Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/kQYWf/